# Wordpress setting image height on import

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a bit of trouble with an unfamiliar wordpress theme. My featured images are all 870 x 550 and yet when i put them in they are resized to 870 x 490, with an ugly crop. I have found a couple of CSS entries with a value of 490px so I changed them to 550px (see code snippet).

```
div.featured-media-container {width:870px; height:550px;}
div.featured-media-container img {width:870px; height:550px;}
```

This has made the container the right size, and resized my image to fill it, but the crop still remains so the image is stretched. How do I stop them being cropped when I drop them in?

Thanks.

Oh, here's the page in question: http://www.decentdesign.co.uk/portfolio/east-wing-coffee/

Comment: Can you paste the code that brings the image here? Should be a mix between php and html, or maybe just php.

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot but I really don't understand :(

Comment: How do you set up that featured image? Is it inserted via the thumbnail option within a post, page? Or anotherway? Give a look in the admin at Settings > Media and tell us what's there.

Comment: The theme has a portfolio section, I guess that's a custom non-WP thing. When I add a new project there is a Featured Image box in the right column with a "set featured image" button. When I click that it comes up with a variation of the Add New Media dialogue. In Settings > Media I can see thumbs are set to 150 x 150, medium images have a max width 297 and height 400, large images i already changed to max width 870 and height 550.

Comment: Ok so you'll have to find the place in the code where the image is being loaded. There, there's probably a simple attribute hard coded within the img tag that would be the cause. Do a search within your files (theme files) for this **featured-media-container**. Check within single.php at first then the other files. When located, change the height attribute of the image tag within the div **featured-media-container**.

Comment: I just checked all the php files. The only one that looked promising was functions.php, which had the following:

// Add support for Featured Image in blog posts and pages

    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {

     add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

     set_post_thumbnail_size( 605, 340, true );

    }

I commented out the set_post_thumbanil_size but it made no difference. I was intrigued by this because if you scale up 605 x 340 maintaining proportions, you get 870 x 489...

Comment: I fixed it Kevin! Just below the code I mentioned above I found this line : add_image_size( 'udt-full-width-image', 870, 490, true ); - I changed the 490 to 550 and everything is good in the world!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, that was my next idea, checking the source of the thumbnail creation. Remember that changing this value in the add_image_size() function won't update the already created extra images. After that wou would have to use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/ to re-create them.

Answer (score 0):

You Just DO one thing from your wp admin panel

**go to settings > Media**

and change the size according to your nedd. For reference take a look of below attached image

that's it Very Simple

[image]

Comment: after this you have to regenerate your thumbnails because in wordpress  the old images are same that they have so please regenerate it and it will work am sure! Let me know?